# Slow mysql of a PHP Board

Tags: php, mysql, forum

I have multiple tables of a php board.

I need an effective query, to select all categories, all topics, last post of topics, with the posted user. With my query it takes 5-8 seconds to run it.
I did an optimize with last_post_id field into topics table, but I need a better solution for it.

**Structure**

```
forum_categories ~ 15 lines
id|name|...

forum_topics ~ 150 lines
id|name|category_id|...

forum_posts ~ 1.000.000 lines
id|body|topic_id|user_id|...

users ~ 30.000 lines
id|username|...


category 1
 - topic 1
    - last post1 | user1
 - topic 2
    - last post2 | user2
 ...
category 2
 - topic 3
   - last post3 | user3
 ...
...
```

**Last query** (This was a help from my friend. But this also was so slow. )

```
SELECT c.NAME     AS category, 
       t.NAME     AS topic, 
       p.body     AS post, 
       p.username AS username 
FROM   forum_categories AS c 
       JOIN forum_topics AS t 
         ON t.category_id = c.id 
       JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM   (SELECT p.body, 
                            p.topic_id, 
                            u.username 
                     FROM   forum_posts AS p 
                            JOIN users AS u 
                              ON u.id = p.user_id 
                     ORDER  BY p.id DESC) AS t 
             GROUP  BY topic_id) AS p 
         ON t.id = p.topic_id
```

**Exaplain query**

[image: pma explain query]

**Statistic of query**

Headers are: sort, status, time | status, all time, pct. time, calls, time
[image: Statistic]

Comment: Sounds like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Anyway, you should post your queries, otherwise there is no way to optimize them.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I fix it.

Comment: So have you done an EXPLAIN on the query? Have you considered the indexes on your tables?

Comment: If we can have your `EXPLAIN` output as well, that would be great. Also, roughly how many rows does each table hold?

Comment: Added explain query, Row numbers are described in table structure

Comment: All foreing keys are indexed, in all tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ***"last post of topics"*** is key point of your query. That's why you used `ORDER BY` on most inner query but this makes two sub-queries.

### Updated version

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE last_post_per_topic_t ENGINE = MEMORY
SELECT topic_id, MAX(id) AS id -----+
FROM forum_posts                    --> find last post id per topic
GROUP BY topic_id; -----------------+

ALTER TABLE last_post_per_topic_t ADD INDEX (id, topic_id);

SELECT *
FROM forum_categories AS c INNER JOIN forum_topics t ON c.id = t.category_id
INNER JOIN forum_posts p ON p.topic_id = t.id
INNER JOIN last_post_per_topic_t ON last_post_per_topic_t.topic_id = t.id
  AND last_post_per_topic_t.id = p.id;
INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id;
```

### first version

```
SELECT *
FROM forum_categories AS c INNER JOIN forum_topics t ON c.id = t.category_id
INNER JOIN forum_posts p ON p.topic_id = t.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT topic_id, MAX(id) AS id -----+
    FROM forum_posts                    --- find last post_id per topic
    GROUP BY topic_id    ---------------+
) last_post_per_topic_t ON last_post_per_topic_t.topic_id = t.id
  AND last_post_per_topic_t.id = p.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but now its selecting all of posts and joins the user,category,and topic to it.

Comment: @TamásSzabó I've updated. What about this? It uses not inline view but physical table, so that MySQL can optimize better way.

Comment: Ah, sorry, your first version was good, i was group bying by a bad key, used **id** instead of **topic_id**. With the first solution it runs at ~ 600ms.

Comment: With the last edition it runs at 10 ms. I still have to figure out, how to create table with my php fw. But looks like fast. Thanks.

Comment: I was wrong. When I run it with pdo, it still has 600 ms delay.
I'm not sure its wrong. Still much more better than 7-8 seconds. Maybe this is the best result to do this.